# htaccess restrict from folder which is other domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have issue which might be simple to solve with htaccess.

The main domain package is like www.domain.com and I have been adding new domains into my plan and those have been made as dns redirects to subfolders in that main domain package. What I have not realized is that anyone could access those new domains by entering www.domain.com/otherdomain

The hosting company says that those should have been ordered to be place one level higher but I did not know that. Is there way to restrict that IF someone accidentally finds or tests the example, that "otherdomain" would not allow redirects from www.domain.com? or what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to places rule as first rule in the `otherdomain/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if hostname in request is domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domian\.com$
# return forbidden error
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a bit, is there any other response which could give 404? I mean I want to hide existence of those subdomains related to main one.

Comment: This will actually bock all the visitors and search bots, so these directories will not be listed in any search engines.

Comment: Did you try this rule?

Comment: I did not block all the access, it gives 403. I don't know about search engines tho.

Comment: By block/forbidden I meant 404 only :) Yes 403 status will stop any search engines to index it.